# Property 'method' in type' is not assignable to the same property in base type

Tags: typescript

We implemented a generic type with optional, it uses a default type otherwise it should use the type set when running a method.

```
type Test = {
  a: number;
  b: string;
}
interface IApple {
  // we can call it as `method()` fallbacks to `Test` type or with custom type like `method<AnotherType>()`
  method<T=Test>(): Promise<T> 
}
```

Now when I write a class like this.

```
class Apple implements IApple {
   method() {
    return Promise.resolve({
        a: 10, 
        b: 'test',
     } as Test)
}
```

Getting type error

```
Property 'method' in type 'Apple' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'IApple'.
  Type '() => Promise<{ a: number; b: string; }>' is not assignable to type '<T = Test>() => Promise<T>'.
    Type 'Promise<{ a: number; b: string; }>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<T>'.
      Type '{ a: number; b: string; }' is not assignable to type 'T'.
        'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to '{ a: number; b: string; }'.
```

Comment: because your returning object has the same shape of Test but it is not a Test object. You need to type it first. BTW why your function signature has a Promise as return type, if the core function is not async or not returning a Promise?

Comment: I have updated my question, still same error.